# Xaml Parse Error Wrong Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Getting parse error bug, and I'm using legit parameter.

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" PlaceholderText="Your Note" Margin="14,14,14,70" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"></TextBox>
```

The TextWrapping Property is causing my app to crash. 
I get the E_Runtime_SetValue error. How to fix it? Already rebuild my project.

Comment: [_"TextBox and RichEditBox don't support the WrapWholeWords value for their TextWrapping properties. If you try to use WrapWholeWords as a value for TextBox.TextWrapping or RichEditBox.TextWrapping an invalid argument exception is thrown."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.textwrapping)

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't get it I used auto Complete, why shouldn't it work? So it's a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It is a valid enum member so you'll see it autocompleted, but it's not supported on TextBox as you see.

Comment: Personally I don't get "WrapWholeWords" as an Intellisense option. Wrap, NoWrap, WrapWithOverflow.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok It worked in windows phone apps i guess so I was confused ty

Comment: @ToddSprang That's strange, I checked 2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not allowed.

TextBox and RichEditBox don't support the WrapWholeWords value for their TextWrapping properties. If you try to use WrapWholeWords as a value for TextBox.TextWrapping or RichEditBox.TextWrapping an invalid argument exception is thrown.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.textwrapping